# Replacing variable in HTTP POST URL from a list

Tags: http, xmlhttprequest, jmeter, http-post, http-get

I have been playing around with HURL and an API to post tasklists to a CRM system. Have that working for an individual project which is great.

Currently, my code looks like this -

```
POST: /projects/**project_ID**/tasklists.json
BODY:
{
"todo-list" : {     
   "name": "June 2017",
"todo-list-template-id" : "xxxxx"
}}
```

Essentially, I want to replace project_ID with a list of id's I have. E.G

- 57425
- 4583
- 28328
- 9492
- 35435

Any recommendations on where to start? This is a learning process so even directing me to the right documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

---

EDIT:

I've discovered JMeter and currently have it setup as below -

**User Defined Variables**
Project_ID - xxxxx
Project_ID - xxxxx

**HTTP Request**
/projects/${project_ID}/tasklists.json

Now the issue is that the script only uses the 1st variable and doesn't loop into the second variable. Any ideas?

Comment: Is your projectid an integer sequence ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing the same problem, just with reading in a ton of urls and solved it via [this](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)

just set your thread to run forever and set the "stop thread on EOF" option in the CSV config to "true", it will automatically stop when it's done reading all your IDs

Comment: Exactly what I did - thank you. For others who read this - what I did was create User Parameters along with CSV Data Set Config. I had all my project_ID's in column 1 of my CSV. Under User Parameters, I referred to the CSV Data. As above, I stopped thread on EOF and boom - 35 HTTP POST's in 4 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Just use [__StringFromFile() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile) like:

```
/projects/${__StringFromFile(/path/to/the/file/with/IDs.csv,,,)}/tasklists.json
```

The `__StringFromFile()` function reads the next line from the given file each time it's being called so it seems to be the easiest way of parameterizing your scenario.

See [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) article to get familiarized with the JMeter Functions concept.